# How to search data from elasticsearach using python?

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

Here is the json:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OR3LcpPcQ2GTzXhWp",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "j2ee",
          "company name": "avr",
          "No of emp": 50
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OVa_rpPcQ2GTzXhWu",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "c++",
          "company name": "abc",
          "No of emp": 70
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9ORxCxpPcQ2GTzXhWn",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "python",
          "company name": "avr",
          "No of emp": 20
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OVRYIpPcQ2GTzXhWs",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "c#",
          "company name": "edge",
          "No of emp": 70
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OVw9ypPcQ2GTzXhWx",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "oracle",
          "company name": "wipro",
          "No of emp": 90
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OVmx6pPcQ2GTzXhWv",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "c",
          "company name": "hcl",
          "No of emp": 70
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OVtvRpPcQ2GTzXhWw",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "sql",
          "company name": "wipro",
          "No of emp": 90
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OV6r9pPcQ2GTzXhWz",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "elastic",
          "company name": "avr",
          "No of emp": 60
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9ORt68pPcQ2GTzXhWm",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "python",
          "company name": "avr",
          "No of emp": 100
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9ORzv0pPcQ2GTzXhWo",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "JAVA",
          "company name": "avr",
          "No of emp": 30
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OVV0SpPcQ2GTzXhWt",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": ".net",
          "company name": "networks",
          "No of emp": 70
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "skills",
        "_id": "AV9OV2dUpPcQ2GTzXhWy",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "skill": "mongo",
          "company name": "wipro",
          "No of emp": 90
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my mappings:

```
{
  "state": "open",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "creation_date": "1508846730700",
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "uuid": "rfgABcAlTC2sXDlqpKerjw",
      "version": {
        "created": "1070299"
      },
      "number_of_replicas": "0"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "skills": {
      "properties": {
        "No of emp": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "skill": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "company name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": []
}
```

Problems : 
1) I want to print the `company name`, if `No of emp` are grater than 50.

2) I want to print the `skill`, if `No of emp` are less than 50.

3) I want to print the `skill`, if `No of emp` are grater than 50 or `company name` is `avr`.

4) I want to print the `company name`, if `No of emp` are grater than 50 and `skill` is `j2ee` or `company name` is `avr`.

Using python i should solve this problems.
I am using elasticsearch 1.7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your Python code so far?

Comment: I just printed all the documents presented in the index...I am new to elastic search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
# create the elastic client instace:
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="IPadd:port")
# now you can execute the queries and get the response:
# response = es.search(index=index, body=query)
```

To answer your four questions:

1) Print the `company name`, if `No of emp` are grater than 50:

I assume you want all the companies' names which have more then 50 employees. So I going to use (here and at the rest of the quetions) [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) -

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "No of emp": {
              "gt": 50
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "companies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2) I want to print the `skill`, if `No of emp` are less than 50:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "No of emp": {
              "lt": 50
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "skills": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "skill"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3) I want to print the `skill`, if `No of emp` are grater than 50 or `company name` is `avr`:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "No of emp": {
              "gt": 50
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "company name": "avr"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "skills": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "skill"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4) I want to print the `company name`, if `No of emp` are grater than 50 and `skill` is `j2ee` or `company name` is `avr`:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "No of emp": {
              "gt": 50
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "skill": "j2ee"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "company name": "avr"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "companies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer...Thanks